# Remove dollar sign and commas in textWatcher in android

Tags: android, android-emulator, click, android-edittext, textwatcher

while typing integers in edittext, i made to come doller sign alone with commas and its working properly, and now i want to get only integers from them and store in variable for some calculations, how this can be done? thanks in advance..

and this was my code..

private TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

```
     @Override public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { 

     }
     boolean isEdiging;

     @Override public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

     @Override public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
         if(isEdiging) return;
         isEdiging = true;



         String str = s.toString().replaceAll( "[^\\d]", "" );
         double s1 = Double.parseDouble(str);

         NumberFormat nf2 = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
         ((DecimalFormat)nf2).applyPattern("$ ###,###.###");
         s.replace(0, s.length(), nf2.format(s1));
         isEdiging = false;
     }
};
```

Comment: Your answers are here: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1562582/vishnu?tab=questions. 25% is very low!

Comment: your answer is this: people here offer their time and knowledge for free, yet they expect to be paid back with reputation points. It is sort of currently here. And you are simply not paying.

Comment: I think 25% is perfectly acceptable for a starter, why all the fuss